# Reverse AJAX with IIS/ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, reverse-ajax

Can you suggest me some techniques/API's for doing a Reverse AJAX with ASP.NET? I checked WebSync, but thats too expensive, any free API's?

And I would also be please to get some tutorials regarding the same..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think it is better known as "Comet"

Comment: but Comet works with IIS/ASP.NET?

Comment: Comet is the name of the technique, and yes there are modules that work with asp.net

Comment: Thanks! Can you please suggest me some good tutorials for the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

James, Comet is the name of the technique and not a specific code.

Check this sites for comet with asp.net

http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/

or

http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/

Comment: I've been fighting with this problem for two days now, and don't have a solution built yet. But your answer has helped me stop looking in the wrong places! Now I can go try to find a simple "COMET" solution to my problem with posting back to a client from the server. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[PokeIn](http://pokein.com) gives you an enhanced JSON functionality to make your server side objects available in client side. Simply, it is a Reverse Ajax library which makes it easy to call JavaScript functions from C#/VB.NET and to call C#/VB.NET functions from JavaScript. It has numerous features like event ordering, resource management, exception handling, marshaling, Ajax upload control, mono compatibility, WCF & .NET Remoting integration and scalable server push.

There is a free community license option for this library and the licensing option is quite cost effective in comparison to others.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free edition of Lightstreamer - you'd have to look at the feature list though.
http://www.lightstreamer.com/products.htm