# Real-time ASP.NET MVC Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, real-time

I need to add a "real-time" element to my web application. Basically, I need to detect "changes" which are stored in a SQL Server table, and update various parts of the UI when a change has occured.

I'm currently doing this by polling. I send an ajax request to the server every 3 seconds asking for any new changes - these are then returned and processed. It works, but I don't like it - it means that for each browser I'll be issuing these requests frequently, and the server will always be busy processing them. In short, it doesn't scale well.

Is there any clever alternative that avoids polling overhead?

**Edit**

In the interests of completeness, I'm updating this to mention the solution we eventually went with - [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR). It's OS and comes from Microsoft. It's risen in popularity, and I can heartily recommend this, or indeed WebSync which we also looked at.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555462/reverse-ajax-with-iis-asp-net

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/), a comet server designed for ASP.NET/IIS.

In particular, what I would do is use the [SQL Dependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class, and when you detect a change, use [RequestHandler.Publish("/channel", data);](http://docs.frozenmountain.com/#class=server-getting-started-publishing-data) to send out the info to the appropriate listening clients.

Should work pretty nicely.

Comment: tho in fairness, it is pretty amazing (WebSync). the demos (especially the maps one - you'll need 2 browser windows open for that) are very simple but instructive

Comment: WebSync does look pretty cool, though ideally I'd like a free solution (or rather, the client would like a free solution!).

Comment: Hehe, fair enough Jakub ;). For anyone who's wondering what he's talking about - I'm one of the developers of WebSync, employed by Frozen Mountain :). Not trying to hide anything here.

Comment: @Matt - don't they always? :) The question is, what's "free" - your time to implement, vs. purchasing an existing solution...seems like I have that conversation many times a day. But, that's probably a question for a different place :-D

Comment: On a second look at this, I am suitably impressed, and am waiting for a response from the boss about the possibility of purchasing :)

Answer (score 5):

taken directly from the link refernced by Jakub (i.e.):

[Reverse AJAX with IIS/ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555462/reverse-ajax-with-iis-asp-net)

***[PokeIn on codeplex](http://pokein.codeplex.com/) gives you an enhanced JSON functionality to make your server side objects available in client side. Simply, it is a Reverse Ajax library which makes it easy to call JavaScript functions from C#/VB.NET and to call C#/VB.NET functions from JavaScript. It has numerous features like event ordering, resource management, exception handling, marshaling, Ajax upload control, mono compatibility, WCF & .NET Remoting integration and scalable server push.
There is a free community license option for this library and the licensing option is quite cost effective in comparison to others.***

I've actually used this and the community edition is pretty special. well worth a look as this type of tech will begin to dominate the landscape in the coming months/years. the codeplex site comes complete with asp.net mvc samples.

Comment: jakub -how strange, i actually visited that link no less than 10 minutes ago- thanks for the heads up. have changed to direct codeplex project link

Answer (score 5):

No matter what: you will always be limited to the fact that HTTP is (mostly) a one-way street. Unless you implement some sensible code on the client (ie. to listen to incoming network requests) anything else will involve polling the server for updates, no-matter what others will tell you.

We had a similar requirement: to have very fast response time in one of our real-time web applications, serving about 400 - 500 clients per web server. Server would need to notify the clients almost within 0.1 of a second (telephony & VoIP).

In the end we implemented an [Async Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.aspx). On each polling request we put the request to sleep for 5 seconds, waiting for a semaphore pulse signal to respond to the client. If the 5 seconds are up, we respond with a "no event" and the client will post the request again (immediately). This resulted in very fast response times, and we never had any problems with up to 500 clients per machine.. no idea how many more we could add before the polling requests might create a problem.

Comment: This is pretty much what I did. You end up with a queue that you poll and pull down the events as needed. I am pretty sure in fact thats how stack overflow works and its top of the page "toast" works.

Comment: this sounds like a very good common sense approach to indeterminable pinging.. like it +1

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [this article](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/08/ajax-client-for-http-polling-duplex-wcf.html)

I've read somewhere (didn't remember where) that using this WCF feature make the host process handle requests in a way that didn't consume blocked threads.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the restrictions on you application you can use Silverlight to do this connection. You don't need to have any UI for Silverlight, but you can use Sockets have a connection that accepts server side pushes of data.